# Calculating np.mean predict with percent filter

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to find np.mean of clf.predict only for rows where one of predicted values percent more then 80%

My current code:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
clf.fit(X, Y)

dropIndexes = []

for i in range(len(X)):
    proba = clf.predict_proba ([X.values[i]])
    if (proba[0][0] < 80 and proba[0][1] < 80):
        dropIndexes.append(i)

#delete all rows where predicted values less then 80

X.drop(dropIndexes, inplace=True)
Y.drop(dropIndexes, inplace=True)

#Returns the average of the array elements
print ("ERR:",  np.mean(Y != clf.predict(X)))
```

Is it possible to make this code more quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is unnecessary, as `predict_proba` works on matrices. You can replace it with

```
 prd = clf.predict_proba(X)
 dropIndexes = (prd[:, 0] < 0.8) & (prd[:, 1] < 0.8)
```